# How to route to root after submitting form in angular

Tags: angular, forms, routes

After posting a recommendation I want to return to the root of the page in my case localhost:8080. However after the post it tries to open localhost:8080//newrec?recommendation="the entered recommendation" Does anyone know how to route to the root after submitting a form?

```
   // post("/api/recommendations")
    createRecommendation(newRecommendation: Recommendation): Promise<Recommendation> {
      return this.http.post(this.recommendationsUrl, newRecommendation)
                 .toPromise()
                 .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all why using promises?

something like this should work

```
return this.http.post(this.recommendationsUrl, newRecommendation)
                 .subscribe(() => // success case,
                 (error) => // error case);
```

for redirecting you will need to use the [angular router component](https://angular.io/guide/router):

```
this.router.navigate(['/']);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not solve my problem. Still does not route me to the deserved page after submitting the recommendation via my recommendationservice.